# Selenium code does not click on the element on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, raspberry-pi4

I am aiming to use my raspberry pi to test a webpage with python/selenium. The code works well on my desktop but the raspberry fail to handle the pop up:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.swoodoo.ch")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Schliessen']"))).click()
```

No problem on the desktop (ubuntu 22.04 or linux mint)
On the raspberry (raspberian or ubuntu 22.04) I get a timeout exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/flights/flights2.py", line 19, in <module>
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Schliessen']"))).click()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I tried the following (all below works well on the desktop!):

**a)** I manually click the banner away -> the whole program fine, incl. the functions to grad text out of a search result. However, it is not automated

**b)** I added waiting time (

```
time.sleep(x))
```

between all lines, long waiting time (30+) -> no change

**c)** I changed the code to the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.swoodoo.ch")

time.sleep(5)

element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Schliessen']")

time.sleep(5)

element.click()
```

-> The computer finds the Element but it is not clickable, error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/flights/flights2.py", line 23, in <module>
    element.click()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 93, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 401, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.105)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x00557fda2268 <unknown>
#1 0x00557fbcbb08 <unknown>
#2 0x00557fbfd50c <unknown>
#3 0x00557fbf32d0 <unknown>
#4 0x00557fbf2cac <unknown>
#5 0x00557fc264c8 <unknown>
#6 0x00557fbf18f0 <unknown>
#7 0x00557fde52f4 <unknown>
#8 0x00557fde7b9c <unknown>
#9 0x00557fdd1cd4 <unknown>
#10 0x00557fde83bc <unknown>
#11 0x00557fdc6d64 <unknown>
#12 0x00557fe01cd0 <unknown>
#13 0x00557fe01e40 <unknown>
#14 0x00557fe1a6f0 <unknown>
```

**d)** Last idea was to use javascript for the click

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

-> No error message, no action

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Is the webpage visibly rendering the same? Media queries could be causing the content to switch to a mobile view or something similar

Comment: Yes,looks exactly the same on all devices.... Using even same Chromium version...

Answer (score 0):

Generally `<div>` tags aren't clickable. So to click on the <kbd>X</kbd> icon you need to target the descendant `<span>` inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.swoodoo.ch/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Schliessen'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.swoodoo.ch/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Schliessen']/span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the tow suggestions, unfortunately both end up with the same timeout error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/flights/flights2.py", line 19, in <module>
    wait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Schliessen']/span"))).click()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

This drives me crazy........

Comment: @vhuber A bit clueless as the locators worked on my Win10 system seamlessly.

Comment: Me too, as it works on my linux desktop as well......